# Send expression in java

Tags: java, code-duplication

I have two methods that both get a user object from an Arraylist.

```
public User getUser(int userID) {
    ListIterator<User> listIterator = listOfLoggedInUsers.listIterator();
    User user;
    while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
        user = listIterator.next();
        if (user.getID() == userID) {
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public User getUser(String username) {
    ListIterator<User> listIterator = listOfLoggedInUsers.listIterator();
    User user;
    while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
        user = listIterator.next();
        if (user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since the methods only differ in the if statment how could code duplication be reduced? 
Is it possible to send a expression/dynamic boolean in the arguments for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both answers. This was how I made it work.

```
public User getUserByID(int userID) {
    return getUser(user -> user.getID() == userID);
}

public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    return getUser(user -> user.getUsername().equals(username));
}

private User getUser(Predicate<User> predicate) {
    ListIterator<User> listIterator = listOfLoggedInUsers.listIterator();
    User user;
    while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
        user = listIterator.next();
        if (predicate.test(user)) {
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a common method that accepts a predicate and return the first matching element:

```
private User getUser(Predicate<User> predicate) {
    return listOfLoggedInUsers.stream()
            .filter(predicate)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}

public User getUser(int userID) {
    return getUser(user -> user.getID() == userID);
}

public User getUser(String username) {
    return getUser(user -> user.getUsername().equals(username));
}
```

Comment: I *kinda* wish you didn't overload the `getUser` method with the internal-facing one...but otherwise this is what I would do as well.

Comment: I would also rename the private getUser to getUser0 or some other name (for example, findUser(Predicate) and findUserById(), findUserByName()).

Answer (score 1):

You could combine them both as follows with the use of a [`Predicate<User>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)

```
public User getUser(Predicate<User> predicate){
       for (User u : listOfLoggedInUsers)
           if (predicate.test(u)) return u;
       return null;
}
```

then call it as:

```
getUser(u -> u.getUserId() == userID)
getUser(u -> u.getUsername().equals(username))
...
...
```

To make this better and more readable you may consider making `getUser`

```
private User getUser(Predicate<User> predicate){
        for (User u : listOfLoggedInUsers)
           if (predicate.test(u)) return u;
        return null;
}
```

and then expose two public methods

```
public User getUserById(int userID) { return getUser(u -> u.getUserId() == userID); }

public User getUserByName(String name) { return getUser(u -> u.getUsername().equals(name)); }
```

Comment: Why use an iterator at all if you're using a `Predicate`?

Comment: @Makoto the question was whether we could combine both methods into one, adding anything else is a bonus. Nevetherless, edited if it makes things better.